# Updating dataGridView value from another form

Tags: c#

hello experts help please, i have two form in my project and one of those form1 have dataGridView and i want to update the gridview according to text value from form 2,

i had done updating dgv but all row updated on button click event
ex. i have 4 rows different description and cell value after click event
all those 4 rows updating to 1 value.

```
Form 1
dgv cellmouseclick event
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                _choosenPart = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                _choosenQty = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                _choosenPrice = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                _choosenAmount = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                _choosenTotal = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            }

            FrM_Edit EditGV = new FrM_Edit(this);
            EditGV.Show();



In form 2 

//constructor
Form F2_main = null;
public FrM_Edit(Form DgVForm1)
    {
     F2_main=DgVForm1;
     InitializeComponent();
    }

button click event
            r2main_choosenPart = textBox1.Text;
            r2main_choosenQty = textBox2.Text;
            r2main_choosenPrice = textBox3.Text;
            r2main_choosenAmount = textBox4.Text;
            r2main_choosenTotal = textBox5.Text;


            DataGridView Main_dg = (DataGridView)F2_main.Controls["dataGridView2"];            
            for (int i = 0; i < Main_dg.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = r2main_choosenPart;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = r2main_choosenQty;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = r2main_choosenPrice;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = r2main_choosenAmount;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = r2main_choosenTotal;            
            }
            this.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//this for loop takes all rows of your DataGridView. And it is normal that you see that all rows are changing because for all rows, you apply the same code.

```
        DataGridView Main_dg = (DataGridView)F2_main.Controls["dataGridView2"];            
        for (int i = 0; i < Main_dg.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
          Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = r2main_choosenPart;
          Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = r2main_choosenQty;
          Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = r2main_choosenPrice;
          Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = r2main_choosenAmount;
          Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = r2main_choosenTotal;            
        }
```

Instead, you should update only the row that you want to updaate.
You can use differents methods.
For exemple:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Main_dg.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
          if( Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == "valueToChange") //Checking an ID or other value.
           {
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = r2main_choosenPart;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = r2main_choosenQty;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = r2main_choosenPrice;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = r2main_choosenAmount;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = r2main_choosenTotal; 
            break; // To break after finding the row that you are looking for.           
           }
        }
```

Or

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Main_dg.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
          if(i == 2) //to update the third row of the grid.
           {
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = r2main_choosenPart;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = r2main_choosenQty;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = r2main_choosenPrice;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = r2main_choosenAmount;
            Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = r2main_choosenTotal;   
            break; // To break after finding the row that you are looking for.    
           }
        }
```

Or you can use your DataGridViews selected row to update.

Comment: @ coskun, got inserted your modification made on my code already clean and rebuild the project but Warning occur "Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison" in this line if (Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == r2main_choosenPart) and the breakpoint jump even the cells.value[0] is the same as result i am looking

Comment: What gives r2main_choosenPart ? Did you try if(Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == r2main_choosenPart.ToString()) for exemple ? Probably, Main_dg.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value is type object and your parameter is a string or another type.

Comment: yes coskun, i add .cell[0].tostring() and also r2main_choosenpart.tostring() but it gives me same respond, the r2main_choosen value is text